# How to add a schema version number to a node in xml using data contracts?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, version, datacontract

I am working with serialization using data contracts and want to add a version number(schema version number in my case) and a check for the same on the very root node of my serialized document.

Something like this :

```
<ReportDocFormat version="1.0.2">
    <FirstNode>
    ...
```

Further, I wan't to use this version number to decide whether or not to deserialize that document for that schema.

I have searched through the specification and on other sites but I can't find any possible ways to do it.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007079/resolving-which-version-of-an-xml-schema-to-use-for-xml-documents-with-a-version ?

Comment: @o_weisman The working of 'VersionAttribute' in mentioned question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007079/resolving-which-version-of-an-xml-schema-to-use-for-xml-documents-with-a-version) is kind of similar I want to have.