# Jaxb: How to replace a class/binding in given object tree while unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a given set of classes to unmarshall a xml into an object tree. Now I get a extended xml and want to replace one class in the object tree with an extended version.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootNode_001>
    <systemId>on the 4</systemId>
    <systemName>give me some more</systemName>
    <person>
        <firstname>James</firstname>
        <lastname>Brown</lastname>
        <address>
            <street>Funky</street>
            <city>Town</city>
            <type>HOME</type> <!-- this is the new field -->
        </address>
    </person>
</RootNode_001>
```

I create a new address class with the new field like this:

```
public class ExtAddress extends Address {
    // inherit from address and add new field
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Now I try to unmarshall into an object tree and I expect `ExtAddress` to be part of the tree like this:

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main ( String argv[] ) throws Exception {
        File file = new File( "basic.xml" );
        Class cls = RootNode.class;

        // create a context with the root node and the replacement class
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( ExtAddress.class, cls );
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal( new StreamSource( file ), cls );
        RootNode rootNode = (RootNode) jaxbElement.getValue();

        System.out.println( rootNode.getClass().getName() );
        System.out.println( rootNode.getPerson().getClass().getName()  );
        // this returns Address but I want ExtAddress
        System.out.println( rootNode.getPerson().getAddress().getClass().getName()  );
    }
}
```

I use no annotations so far. The unmarshalled object tree return `Address` and not `ExtAddress`. If I add a `XmlType` annotation I get an exception:

```
@XmlTyp( name = "address" )
ExtAddress extends Address {
  ...
}

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "address". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at jaxb.standard.Address
        at jaxb.ExtAddress
```

I tried many things but this seems to be very near to a solution. How can I tell jaxb to use an inherited class instead of the original one.

I want to delvier a set of standard classes in a library and be able to change the object tree later as an extension when new fields in xml appear.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the xml with extAddress instead address will do the trick.

Comment: the xml is send by an external system

Comment: If I change ExtAddress to Address (but in another package) I get the following exception: `Two classes have the same XML type name "address". Use XmlType.name and XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at jaxb.standard.Address
  at jaxb.Address`

Answer (score 0):

You should do XML schema versioning instead of this, however it is [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014237/what-are-the-best-practices-for-versioning-xml-schemas) to do it well. There is a [pdf](http://www.xfront.com/Versioning.pdf) in the linked article, you should read it.

I did the "Option 3 Change the schema's targetNamespace" in the past, in this way, you can do the following:

you have different targetNamespaces for every version:

```
targetNamespace="http://www.exampleSchema.com/v1.0"
targetNamespace="http://www.exampleSchema.com/v1.1"
...
```

and you can generate the necessary JAXB classes for each namespace in different group:

```
com.example.schema.generated.v10
com.example.schema.generated.v11
...
```

From here it is up to you how to try to read it:

- you can make a contract, that the file must ends with the version of the schema: file1_v10.xml, file2_v11.xml
- you can try to read with the latest JAXB classes, if it fails, the previous and so on
- you can the first n. line as text of the file, and parse the targetNamespace, and apply the right JAXB
- or you have another [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007079/resolving-which-version-of-an-xml-schema-to-use-for-xml-documents-with-a-version) and so on...

(of course, you have to handle each version separately after unmarshalling, which is not necessarily bad)

**OR**

you can decide so that you are using only 1 schema, and one can only extend the schema with optional (minOccurs="0") elements, it is ugly, and has some limitations, but sometimes it is enough.

**OR**

Or, you can do it in a different way: you can use another XML framework, that supports schema versioning, like this one: [JMRI](http://jmri.sourceforge.net/help/en/html/doc/Technical/XmlSchema.shtml#test) or [JiBX](https://sourceforge.net/p/jibx/mailman/message/25860431/) 
(They are not necessary current or actively developed, just wanted to show some examples. What I really wanted to link is an another one, but unfortunately I forgot its name).

Answer (score 0):

A similar topic is discussed here: [JAXB inheritance, unmarshal to subclass of marshaled class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619761/jaxb-inheritance-unmarshal-to-subclass-of-marshaled-class)

With [jackson 2.8.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.6) you can just write something like

```
@Test
public void readXmlToSelfDefinedPojo2() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    ExtAdress pojo = mapper.readValue(
                    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("52109685.xml"),
                    ExtAdress.class);
    System.out.println(toString(pojo));
}

public String toString(Object obj) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writeValue(w, obj);
    return w.toString();
}
```

It will print

```
{
  "systemId" : "on the 4",
  "type" : "test"
}
```

for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <RootNode_001>
<systemId>on the 4</systemId>
<systemName>give me some more</systemName>
<type>test</type>
<person>
    <firstname>James</firstname>
    <lastname>Brown</lastname>
    <address>
        <street>Funky</street>
        <city>Town</city>
        <type>HOME</type> <!-- this is the new field -->
    </address>
</person>
</RootNode_001>
```

and

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ExtAdress extends Adress {
    public String type;
    public ExtAdress() {
    }
}
```

and

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Adress {
    public String systemId;

    public Adress() {
    }
}
```

Comment: readXmlToSelfDefinedPojo2 -- good method name.  I didn't even know this could be done.

Comment: Are you referring to the trailing '2'? This comes from my test code where I already had a 'readXmlToSelfDefinedPojo' method. Maybe should remove it?

Comment: no, I was serious.  Good name.  the "self defined pojo" is useful lingo for me.  vocabulary.   it's a strong answer.  I didn't notice or care about the numeral :)  but it's fine.

Comment: Thanks. The naming style was inspired by "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship" by Robert C. Martin.