# How to store values in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a table (`REQUESTS`) and it contains 1 column (`XML_DATA`) for xmls.

So if `ID=123` has a row in this table, it should get the corresponding xml.

If xml was retrieved, i need to get all the values with tag `<Mobile>0918xxxx</Mobile>`.

Here is what i have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RqeuestsDBViewData.length; i++) //GETS ROWS FROM TABLE REQUESTS
{
    xmlDetails = test.getDetailsFromXML(mCustUtils, RequestDBViewData[i]); //GETS XML FROM XML_DATA
    String strXmlDetails;
    String strMob;
        if (!AppUtils.isEmpty(xmlDetails)) //IF IT HAS ROW, THEN GET RECORD FROM <MOBILE></MOBILE> TAG
        {
             strXmlDetails = xmlDetails.toString(); //ENTIRE XML
             strMob = StringUtils.substringBetween(strXmlDetails, "<Mobile>", "</Mobile>"); //GETS MOBILE VALUE
        }
```

Now, if there are more than 1 `<Mobile></Mobile>`,

i need to store it in an array using for loop.

How do i store multiple values of strMob in an array?

After stroring all possible strMob, i'm planning to assign the values somewhere else like: `personalInfo[j].setMobile(array/list[j]);`

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Since you don't know how many elements you'll have, it is better that you use a List, rather than an array. You can later turn that list to an array using the toArray() method, if you need to.

Comment: hi @YoavGur, can you show how? because i'm also planning to use this array/list to do something like `personalInfo[j].setMobile(array/list[j]);`

Comment: That's pretty basic java stuff. Here are 2 links that I hope would help: 1. https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-list-collection-tutorial-and-examples , 2. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper XML tool to read your XML.

**Variant 1**

Use Jackson to [parse your XML to a prepared Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52145587/1485527). This will also work for arrays.

**Variant 2**

Read XML to a DOM object

```
public static Element getDocument(String xmlString) {
    return getDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes()));
}

public static Element getDocument(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        root.normalize();
        return root;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

With the aim of XPATH you can than extract your `<Mobile>` elements. See this answer: [Extract content between XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720162)